# Cannot create list of objects in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using ListSerializer for updating and creating list of objects, `update()` works fine but cannot create list of objects (bulk_create).

models.py

```
class TutorUser(models.Model):
    tutor_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      related_name='tutor')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True)

class WorkExperiance(models.Model):
    tutor_work = models.ForeignKey(TutorUser,
                                   related_name='tutor_work',
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    start_year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class WorkExperianceListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tutor_work_mapping = {tutor_work.id: tutor_work for tutor_work in instance}
        data_mapping = {item['id']: item for item in validated_data}
        ret = []
        for tutor_work_id, data in data_mapping.items():
            print(tutor_work_id)
            tutor_work = tutor_work_mapping.get(tutor_work_id, None)
            # print(tutor_work_id)
            if tutor_work is None:
                ret.append(self.child.create(data))
                # print(ret)
            else:
                ret.append(self.child.update(tutor_work,  data))
        for tutor_work_id, tutor_work in tutor_work_mapping.items():
            if tutor_work_id not in data_mapping:
                tutor_work.delete()

class WorkExperianceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = WorkExperianceListSerializer
        model = WorkExperiance
        fields = [
            'id',
            'organization',   
            'start_year',
        ]
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.organization = validated_data.get('organization', instance.organization)
        instance.start_year = validated_data.get('start_year', instance.start_year) 
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class TutorWorkExperiance(APIView):

    def get_object(self, request):
        tutor = TutorUser.objects.get(tutor_user__id=request.user.id)
        tutor_work = WorkExperiance.objects.filter(tutor_work=tutor)
        return tutor_work

    def put(self, request):
        serializer = WorkExperianceSerializer(self.get_object(request), data = request.data, partial = True, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response({"data": "Not valid"})
```

In my opinion the problem is here with ID, because WorkExperiance model foreign key with TutorUser model, and I cannot pass its ID when object is created. I am using only put method for both creating and updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

The issue is requesting post without ID, cause  `id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)` defined in serializer, and also forgot to pass TutorUser Id which foreign key with WorkExperiance.

views.py:

```
def put(self, request):
        tutor = TutorUser.objects.get(tutor_user__id=request.user.id)
        serializer = WorkExperianceSerializer(self.get_object(request), data = request.data, partial = True, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save(tutor_user=tutor)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response({"data": "Not valid"})
```